# MS SQL - finding period a date belongs to given only period start date

Tags: sql-server-2012

Long time reader, first time poster.
I did search and could not find any other question matching this.  all i could find involved having 2 date columns to compare.  If this has indeed been answered before, I apologize for creating a duplicate post.

I have been given a table with 3 columns:

```
Period  (int) - Name (varchar) - StartDate (datetime)
1   Period 1    2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
2   Period 2    2016-02-01 00:00:00.000
3   Period 3    2016-02-29 00:00:00.000
4   Period 4    2016-03-28 00:00:00.000
5   Period 5    2016-04-25 00:00:00.000
6   Period 6    2016-05-23 00:00:00.000
```

I unfortunately do not have the option of altering the table to add a second date column to contain the end date of each period.  The end of each period is the date immediately preceding the listed StartDate.

I will be passed a date and need to find the period to which the date belongs.

Can anyone provide some direction?

Comment: So you want to select the Highest date that is less than your date parameter?   Is that enough of a hint?   The TOP 1 date?

Comment: *face palm*  THANK YOU Tab Alleman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the hint / comment from Tab Alleman above, I built the following:

```
select top 1 period from PeriodDetail
where StartDate <= getdate()
order by startdate desc
```

As GetDate (at this moment) returns 2/19/2016, the correct result is period 2.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Table
WHERE StartDate >= @GivenDate
ORDER BY StartDate
```